# Eigen operator(Index, Index) of a temporary matrix product

Tags: eigen

Let's say i'm only interested in a single (i, j) element of a matrix product, so I do `(A * B)(i, j)`. Will Eigen compute the full product of `A` and `B` and then access the (i, j) element or will it be smart about it and only calculate what's necessary? If not, what can I do about it?

I'm currently doing SVD-based lossy matrix compression for memory reasons, so I want to store the U, S and V matrices of the SVD and compute elements of the original matrix on the fly: `aij = (U * S.asDiagonal() * V.transpose())(i,j)` hereby my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Computing matrix products coefficient-wise is inefficient, and in current version of Eigen, calling operator(i,j) on a matrix product is thus forbidden (at compile time). So if you access most of the aij, it is much better to evaluate it in a temporary. If you access a very few percent of them in a non structured manner, then you can wrap it in a function implementing:

```
return U.row(i) * S.asDiagonal() * V.row(j).transpose();
```

In future version of Eigen, that is 3.3 or maybe 3.4 only, Eigen will automatically propagate the information to the leaves of the expression tree for you.